# Flutter: Future.then() never getting invoked

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, future

I'm currently playing around with Futures in flutter. I've some async functions that return a Future object. I register a Listener on the Future object with then(), so that I can update the ui as soon as the value comes in.
But the result is empty, because then() returns before all notes are loaded from the file system.

```
Future<List<Note>> loadNotes() async { 
 NoteService().findAll().then((result) { 

  result.forEach((note) => print(note.title)); //not printing -> result is emtpty... 

 });
}


//NoteService class
Future<List<Note>> findAll() async {
  return noteRepository.findAll();
}


//NoteRepository class
@override
Future<List<Note>> findAll() async {

  final Directory dir = await directory;

  dir.list().toList().then((List<FileSystemEntity> list) async {
    List<String> paths = List();
    list.forEach((entity) => paths.add(entity.path));

    List<File> _files = List();
    paths.forEach((path) => _files.add(File(path)));

    List<Note> notes = await _extractNotes(_files);
    return Future.value(notes);
 });

 return Future.value(List());    
}

Future<List<Note>> _extractNotes(List<File> _files) async {
List<Note> notes = List();
 _files.forEach((file) {
   String content = file.readAsStringSync();
   print('content: ' + content);   //this is getting printed correctly to the console
   Map<String, dynamic> a = jsonDecode(content);
   if(a.containsKey('codeSnippets')) {
     notes.add(SnippetNoteEntity.fromJson(jsonDecode(content)));
   } else {
     notes.add(MarkdownNoteEntity.fromJson(jsonDecode(content)));
   }
 });
 return Future.value(notes);
```

}

Comment: Maybe an error is thrown. Did you add a catchError(...) after .then(...)?

Comment: I edited my question. Then() is getting called, but it's getting called too early. It should get called after findAll() is finished.

Comment: so return the Future returned by `then` method, now you are returning empty list

Comment: You are not doing anything with the future returned by `dir.list().toList().then(...)`. Either await it or return it (or both, for the heck of it!)

Comment: oh wow..... I somehow missed that ^^